# Why does mean give NA?

Tags: r, mean

I have a list of numeric (non-NA) data which I can properly return `sum`, `sd`, but not `mean`. I can calculate the mean by myself by `sum(data)/length(data)`, but `mean(data)` returns `NA`. If it matters, the way I am calculating it is by sorting the data, then taking the 7 largest as shown:

```
tQs = sort(dat[ist,7:16]);
tQs = tQs[4:10];
print(tQs);
cat(sprintf("sum : %.2f\n", sum(tQs)));
cat(sprintf("avg : %.2f\n", sum(tQs)/length(tQs)));
cat(sprintf("mean: %.2f\n", mean(tQs)));
cat(sprintf("std : %.2f\n", sd(tQs)));
```

Here is the output:

```
   Quiz4 Quiz2 Quiz1 Quiz3 Quiz5 Quiz7 Quiz10
27    60    80   100   100   100   100    100
sum : 640.00
avg : 91.43
mean: NA
std : 15.74
```

Any idea why `mean` isn't working?

EDIT: Turning on `warnings()` at the end says: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: what about using `mean(tQs,na.rm=T)`?

Comment: What is `class(tQs)`?

Comment: It says it is `data.frame`

Comment: You did NOT calculate the mean with sum(.)/length(.). You got an answer but it wasn't what you thought it was.

Comment: How is `sum(.)/length(.)` not the same thing as mean?

Comment: Please look up what `length` means in the context of dataframes. It will do you more good than if I spoonfeed the answers.

Comment: Haha, thank you for not spoonfeeding me. I might gag. I ask because I do, in fact, get the exact same answer as I would with `mean`. I am writing some code which I had previously written in `MATLAB` so I can validate that `sum(.)/length(.)` does, in fact, return the mean of my array.

Comment: That will only be true in a trivial case with single row object. Your presentation did not imply that you only had a single row since we didn't know what `'ist'` might have been. The goal here should be learning how to do this correctly in the general cases and using `length` in this manner is a common newb-error. And do learn the difference between an R 'data.frame' and an R 'array'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mean does not work on `data.frames`. It only works on vectors and matrices.

If you try

```
 mean(as.matrix(tQs))
```

it should work - assuming there is no problem with the underlying data.

Comment: That is true but actual surprise is that `sd` didn't also fail.

Comment: Thanks, how do I turn my `data.frames` object into a vector?

Comment: @Laurbert515 Answer has been edited to show how to change your data  to a matrix and get the mean

Comment: Also consider using `unlist` which I suspect might be faster if you do not need to be doing anything with the dimensions.